# Vim - Show active spell checking languages in status line

Tags: vim, statusbar

I'd like to customize the **status line** in vim to show the languages the spell checker is checking for. Something like that

```
File: hello.txt [text][utf8][unix][en,de] CWD: ~ Line: 1/10:1
```

I've added this line to my .vimrc:

```
set statusline+=%{v:lang}
```

However, I get the following result which is not completely what I want

```
File: hello.txt [text][utf8][unix][en_US.utf8] CWD: ~ Line: 1/10:1
```

The major drawback is that I don't see all languages activated (en and de)

I was looking for a variable similar to v:lang. Can anyone show me the most convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's set with the `spelllang` option if you're using the built in spell checker and not a plugin:

```
set statusline+=%{&spelllang}
```